# Search Option inside category

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Django:

I'm trying to make a feature where a user can click on a category, and then search within that category. My problem is I can't seem to get the category pk in the html. I've fried my brain trying to find a way, but no luck yet.

```
  <form class="searchfield" action="{% url 'posts:cat_search' pk=  %}" method="get">
    <button  type="submit" name="button">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
    <input class="searchfield" id="searchbox" name='q' type="text" placeholder="Search">

  </form>
```

I need to specify a category pk for the search, but how?
I can grab all the category pks, but just not the one for the correct category

```
class PostListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Post

    def categories(self):
        return Category.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(created_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-created_date')


class PostCatView(PostListView):
    template_name = 'posts/post_category.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        result_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return Post.objects.filter(label=self.kwargs.get('pk')).order_by('-created_date')




class CategorySearchView(PostCatView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        result = super(PostCatView, self).get_queryset()

        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            query_list = query.split()
            result = result.filter(
                reduce(operator.and_,
                        (Q(title__icontains=q) for q in query_list)) |
                reduce(operator.and_,
                        (Q(body__icontains=q) for q in query_list))
            )
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden type input in HTML form and get pk from the request.

Like this:

```html
<input type="hidden" name"pk" value="<your_category_id>" />
```